# Why doesn't this work in Keras?

Tags: r, deep-learning, keras

I'm playing around with a toy neural network in R trying to learn the `keras` syntax. I'm pretty new to this, so feel like I'm probably missing something simple.

Here's first few rows of my X matrix:

```
train_x <- structure(c(619, 502, 699, 850, 645, 822, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 42, 42, 39, 43, 44, 50, 2, 8, 
1, 2, 8, 7, 0, 159660.8, 0, 125510.82, 113755.78, 0, 1, 3, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 101348.88, 113931.57, 
93826.63, 79084.1, 149756.71, 10062.8), .Dim = c(6L, 11L), .Dimnames = 
list(
c("1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), c("CreditScore", "GeographyGermany", 
"GeographySpain", "GenderMale", "Age", "Tenure", "Balance", 
"NumOfProducts", "HasCrCard", "IsActiveMember", "EstimatedSalary"
)))
```

And here's first few of y:

```
train_y <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)
```

And here's the model I'm trying to train

```
class <- keras_model_sequential()

class %>%
layer_dense(units = 6, input_shape = 11, 
          activation = 'relu', 
          kernel_initializer = "uniform") %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 6, 
          activation = 'relu', 
          kernel_initializer = 'uniform') %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid',
          kernel_initializer = 'uniform')

class %>%
  compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
      loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
      metrics = 'accuracy')
class %>%
  fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size = 10, 
  epochs = 10)

y_hat <- predict_classes(class, test_x)
table(y_hat)
```

I've tried messing around with a bunch of these things, but can't seem to get the model to predict anything but all ones or all zeros. I assume I'm missing something simple...any suggestions?

Comment: I have to admit that I barely know R. But from looking at your code you don´t seem to have normalized your data to values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks @petezurich! The categorical variables are one-hot encoded with one class dropped, though it might not be obvious in above. I've tried both with and without normalizing continuous variables with no change.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with keras but seems you are missing the final softmax activation layer. Can you try replacing the 1 unit layer with `layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')` ? As you want to predict two classes in the final layer.

Comment: @DMU -- thanks for the suggestion. Since this is a binary classification problem (probably should've been clearer about that up front -- sorry!), can't sigmoid be used for final activation layer?